# How can I search a column and display the row of my result

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with the following contents:

```
commA6314   ifosfamide   0     12
home5341209 urokinase    6314  37
```

How do I search the first column and then display the entire row.
For example if the user searches `6314` (notice that there is a `6314` in the first column, first row and another `6314` in the third column second row) the output should be:

```
commA6314   ifosfamide   30     12
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic use-case for `awk`

```
awk '$1 ~ /6314/' file
```

or, if you want to pass the pattern to be matched as a variable

```
awk -v pat="6314" '$1 ~ pat' file
```

A similar approach in perl

```
perl -ane 'print if $F[0] =~ /6314/' file
```